# what is label_gain in LightGBM ranker?

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I basically want to know what that parameter is and what kind of input it takes. I want to understand how to use it in different cases.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't want help with any specific problem, I wanted to know what exactly label_gain was as its not defined properly in the lgbmranker documentation. Maybe its hard to understand because you don't know what lgbmranker is, in that case thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official doc](https://readthedocs.org/projects/testlightgbm/downloads/pdf/latest/),

```
label_gain, default=0,1,3,7,15,31,63,..., type=multi-double
– used in lambdarank, relevant gain for labels. For example, the gain of label 2 is 3 if using default label
gains.
– Separate by ,
```

So essentially if your data has multiple labels, each label will correspond to a different gain value in the optimization process, specified by this list.